# How can I find out (at runtime) which desktop environment that a Qt application is running on?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, desktop-application

I'm using [QSysInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsysinfo.html) to get OS information like the kernel version and OS name, but would also like to get the **desktop environment** ([for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) LXDE, XFCE, Luna, Aero, Aqua). Is there any way that I can do this (at runtime)? Grateful for help!

EDIT: I am looking for a cross-platform solution

Comment: There is no completely reliable way to do this. You can check envars like `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`, `DESKTOP_SESSION`, `KDE_FULL_SESSION` and `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID`. But there is no guarantee that they will be present, and the exact values are not (yet) standardised.